# Using custom icon in the Expand widget in ArcGIS SDK JS?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, widget, icon

Using the [Expand Widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Expand.html) in ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript, how can I specify a custom icon (eg an SVG or PNG image) rather than the Esri Calcite icons?

The `expandIcon` parameter only accepts a string which should match the name of a [Calcite Icon](https://developers.arcgis.com/calcite-design-system/icons/?library=Calcite%20UI) (eg "layers"). I wish to use my own icon instead:

```
const bgExpand = new Expand({
  view: view,
  content: basemapGallery,
  expandIcon: 'https://i.imgur.com/ESUiDwT.png'
});
```

However, this has no effect and the icon is blank.

The `expandIconClass` looks as though it could be used to override this with an icon specified in CSS, but this is now deprecated.

How can I manually choose the icon shown in the Expand widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use purely CSS, so there's no need for for hacks like `layerList.classList.add("iconLayerList")`.

The below CSS works for the above simple case (more complex selector might be necessary with complex maps):

```
div[title=Layers] calcite-icon {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/ESUiDwT.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

JS part stays unchanged:

```
const layerListExpand = new Expand({
    view: view,
    expandTooltip: "Layers",
    expandIcon: '',
    content: new LayerList({
      view: view,
    })
});

view.ui.add(layerListExpand, "top-right");
```

Comment: much cleaner - many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a very hacky workaround to make it work. I'd love to know if someone knows of a better approach.

Firstly, add the expand widget with an empty icon and use the `expandTooltip` property to set its title:

```
const layerListExpand = new Expand({
    view: view,
    expandTooltip: "Layers",
    expandIcon: '',
    content: new LayerList({
      view: view,
    })
});

// Add the expand instance to the ui
view.ui.add(layerListExpand, "top-right");
```

Then add a class to the expand button. I'm using a timeout as there doesn't seem to be an event fired when the widget is added:

```
// add a class to the expand widget
setTimeout(() => {
    const layerList = document.querySelector('.esri-widget--button[title="Layers"]');
    if (layerList){
      layerList.classList.add("iconLayerList")
    }
}, 500);
```

This means you can use CSS to apply the image:

```
.esri-widget--button {
  background-color: #000 !important;
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
}

.esri-expand__container:not(.esri-expand__container--expanded) .esri-expand__panel .esri-widget--button.iconLayerList{
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/ESUiDwT.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Demo at https://codepen.io/slead/pen/qBLJQZL